# Can't remove index.php from url(IP ADDRESS) in codeigniter framework

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have used below code in `htaccess` file to remove `index.php` from url in codeigniter framework

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

It's working fine in local but when in live i am using IP ADDRESS to access my site so it's not removing `index.php`

Comment: place your .htaccess file outside the application folder

Comment: where is `index.php` located? Is it in any folder or lying open in public folder? Make sure that `.htacces` has a same path as of `index.php` file. If you are using IIS then `.htacces` will not work. IIS doesn't read `.htacces`. Use `web.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: I hope you have `$config['index_page'] = '';` in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

you should be doing this using routes in code igniter

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html